# How to hide page contents behind div with transaparent background on scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following markup for which I've made a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QkCVpl7Uqi3DUrSgCB09?p=preview):

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand">MY SITE</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row site-content">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="main-nav">
          <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                <li><a>Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a>Link 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 body-content">
        <!-- Lots of stuff -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I need to have the navbar and navmenu fixed but the contents of the page should hide behind the navbar when scrolling.

How can you hide the contents behind the navbar if there is a background image?

Comment: using `position: relative` and `z-index: (whatever)`?

Comment: @RichardMauritz On which element?

Comment: The `element` you want the content to be `hidden` behind

Comment: Are you trying to use the same background image you use for the body in the header?

Comment: @RichardMauritz Position for the header has to be fixed.

Comment: @WillThresher Yes.  You should see the body background "through" the header.

Comment: `position: fixed` and `z-index: 9999` is also ok. `z-index` needs an `position` eg. `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed` to be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `inherit` it will inherit the parent elements attributes, so first you will need to set the header to use the same background image as your body because you are inheriting no background image or color from the header's container.

Secondly, you need to give the header a position attribute in order to 'fix' it to the top of the page. In your case it looks like you'd like to use the `fixed` position.

Here is an [updated plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/Gx45SvalLxrwhnjgSApR/)